# Handle double quotes in xml conversion using VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, csv

Below is the my input .csv file and I am looking to convert this file to xml format:

```
Lable,name,add1,Add2,Add4,add5,Add3,pin,ref,in,date,cod,val,val2,val3
RAMI,"RAMI, INC                ",                                        ,"RAMI, INC                          ",ABCS,"RAM, ME                              ",IND                                     ,5325,2569,,,,,,8574
,,,,,,,,,6556,10/4/2018,IND,5698,0,6985
RAL,"RAL, LLC        ",                                        ,"RALS, LLC                  ",6958 MADH                   ,"Hyd, TS                           ",IND                                     ,54545,6958,,,,,,12121
,,,,,,,,,25698,10/24/2016,IND,2365.2,0,312.5
,,,,,,,,,249469,10/26/2016,IND,85967.3,0,1507.3
,,,,,,,,,249844,11/9/2016,ISD,987456.34,0,594.34
,,,,,,,,,249965,11/14/2016,IDS,25874.38,0,905.38
BAL,"BALL, LLC        ",                                        ,"BALL, LLC                  ",6958 MADH                   ,"Hyd, TS                           ",IND                                     ,54545,6958,,,,,,12121
,,,,,,,,,25698,10/24/2016,IND,2365.2,0,312.5
,,,,,,,,,249469,10/26/2016,IND,85967.3,0,1507.3
```

As per my logic I am getting out put like below:

```
<Payments>
  <P A01="Lable" A02="name" A03="add1" A04="Add2" A05="Add4" A06="add5" A07="Add3" A08="pin" A09="ref" A010="in" A011="date" A012="cod" A013="val" A014="val2" A015="val3" />
  <P A01="RAMI" A02="&quot;RAMI" A03="INC                &quot;" A04="" A05="&quot;RAMI" A06="INC                          &quot;" A07="ABCS" A08="&quot;RAM" A09="ME                              &quot;" A010="IND" A011="5325" A012="2569" A013="" A014="" A015="">
    <R A01="" A02="" A03="" A04="" A05="" A06="" A07="" A08="" A09="" A010="6556" A011="10/4/2018" A012="IND" A013="5698" A014="0" A015="6985" />
  </P>
  <P A01="RAL" A02="&quot;RAL" A03="LLC        &quot;" A04="" A05="&quot;RALS" A06="LLC                  &quot;" A07="6958 MADH" A08="&quot;Hyd" A09="TS                           &quot;" A010="IND" A011="54545" A012="6958" A013="" A014="" A015="">
    <R A01="" A02="" A03="" A04="" A05="" A06="" A07="" A08="" A09="" A010="25698" A011="10/24/2016" A012="IND" A013="2365.2" A014="0" A015="312.5" />
    <R A01="" A02="" A03="" A04="" A05="" A06="" A07="" A08="" A09="" A010="249469" A011="10/26/2016" A012="IND" A013="85967.3" A014="0" A015="1507.3" />
    <R A01="" A02="" A03="" A04="" A05="" A06="" A07="" A08="" A09="" A010="249844" A011="11/9/2016" A012="ISD" A013="987456.34" A014="0" A015="594.34" />
    <R A01="" A02="" A03="" A04="" A05="" A06="" A07="" A08="" A09="" A010="249965" A011="11/14/2016" A012="IDS" A013="25874.38" A014="0" A015="905.38" />
  </P>
  <P A01="BAL" A02="&quot;BALL" A03="LLC        &quot;" A04="" A05="&quot;BALL" A06="LLC                  &quot;" A07="6958 MADH" A08="&quot;Hyd" A09="TS                           &quot;" A010="IND" A011="54545" A012="6958" A013="" A014="" A015="">
    <R A01="" A02="" A03="" A04="" A05="" A06="" A07="" A08="" A09="" A010="25698" A011="10/24/2016" A012="IND" A013="2365.2" A014="0" A015="312.5" />
    <R A01="" A02="" A03="" A04="" A05="" A06="" A07="" A08="" A09="" A010="249469" A011="10/26/2016" A012="IND" A013="85967.3" A014="0" A015="1507.3" />
  </P>
</Payments>
```

But, in this scenario "RAMI, INC" (second line of csv file) is considered as single value and this should come in single tag (A02 = "RAMI, INC")

Below is the reference logic, which is used:

```
Dim filename As String = "C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\Example File.csv"
        Dim strxmlPath As String = "C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\1.xml"

        If File.Exists(strxmlPath) Then
            File.Delete(strxmlPath)
        End If
        Using w As XmlTextWriter = New XmlTextWriter(strxmlPath, Encoding.UTF8)

            w.WriteStartElement("Payments")

            Dim r As String = Nothing

            Dim theFile() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)

            For Each line As String In theFile
                Dim values = line.Split(",")

                Dim is_header = Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Trim(values(0)))

                If is_header Then
                    If r IsNot Nothing Then
                        w.WriteEndElement()
                    End If

                    w.WriteStartElement("P")
                    r = Trim(values(0))
                Else
                    w.WriteStartElement("R")
                End If
                w.WriteAttributeString("A01", Trim(values(0)))
                w.WriteAttributeString("A02", Trim(values(1)))
                w.WriteAttributeString("A03", Trim(values(2)))
                w.WriteAttributeString("A04", Trim(values(3)))
                w.WriteAttributeString("A05", Trim(values(4)))
                w.WriteAttributeString("A06", Trim(values(5)))
                w.WriteAttributeString("A07", Trim(values(6)))
                w.WriteAttributeString("A08", Trim(values(7)))
                w.WriteAttributeString("A09", Trim(values(8)))
                w.WriteAttributeString("A010", Trim(values(9)))
                w.WriteAttributeString("A011", Trim(values(10)))
                w.WriteAttributeString("A012", Trim(values(11)))
                w.WriteAttributeString("A013", Trim(values(12)))
                w.WriteAttributeString("A014", Trim(values(13)))
                w.WriteAttributeString("A015", Trim(values(14)))

                If Not is_header Then
                    w.WriteEndElement()
                End If
            Next

            If r IsNot Nothing Then
                w.WriteEndElement()
            End If

            w.WriteEndElement()
        End Using


    End Sub
```

Just I need to handle double quotes, Please find the attached image for you reference:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJjh4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't let yourself suffer trying to create your own CSV parser. Microsoft has already made one for you - [TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netframework-4.7.2). There's also an MSDN article on [How to: read from comma-delimited text files in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-read-from-comma-delimited-text-files) which might help you a little more.

Here's a basic example:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser

Dim parsedData As String()
Dim csvFile = New FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\Example File.csv")
csvFile.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
csvFile.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
csvFile.Delimiters = New String() {","}

Do While Not csvFile.EndOfData
    Try
        parsedData = afile.ReadFields()
    Catch ex As FileIO.MalformedLineException
        Stop
    End Try
Loop
```